# Re-propagate a Caught Signal in Linux

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to use sigwait() for SIGSEGV and other signals and then do something (says writing the timestamp to a file).  Then, I would like the program to behave as if the signal were never caught (e.g. a coredump is generated when SIGSEGV happens -- assuming the system is configured for coredump).

I read through couple manpages, and I don't see an obvious way to do so.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You specifically can't suppress normal SIGSEGV handling, because it's handled outside your process (the signal is just a courtesy so you can do any cleanup you need)

Comment: I am wondering the same for `SIGINT`. I just want to do something on `SIGINT` in my signal handler then pass it on for default handling but don't see a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a signal handler that won't cause the program to crash.  Once you receive the signal, you'll enter the signal handler, and after executing the signal handler (write to file you said), you'll reenter the program where you left off.

If you want a core dump, you can use the linux core(5) command and it will create a core dump in your signal handler without ending your process.

http://www.alexonlinux.com/signal-handling-in-linux#signal_masks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can not handle few signals the way you want to for example

```
SIGKILL
SIGSEGV
```

as manual itself states **The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored**
check below links

[SIGNAL(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)  and  [SIGNAL(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)  **These links should provide good enough details on signal handling in linux**

You can however register a signal handler to handle few other signals 
to list signals in operating system like linux you can use below command

```
kill -l
```

and as far as generating core dump is conserned its generated by operating system [click here for more info](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/core-dump)

check the example code [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/)